# Blocking on many locks/futures/etc. until any is ready

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Is it possible to block on a group of locks/futures/any blockable entities, until any one of them is ready? The idea is that we can do:

```
std::vector<std::future<T>> futures = ...;
auto ready_future = wait_until_an_element_is_ready(futures);
process(ready_future.get());
```

I remember libraries like libevent, libev, and libuv have this kind of ability for IO tasks. But I don't know if these can be done for locks/futures.

A way I thought of to sort of achieve this is to have the futures call a handler upon completion, but at the same time compare-and-exchange the handler to null so that no other futures can call it. This requires the coordination of the futures, however, so can't be done for locks.

**UPDATE:** There seems to be a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4107.html#future) for it for C++2x.

Comment: RE: update. Yes. It is in Concurrency TS, which sadly wan't ready in time for C++17. SOme cmpilers might have implemented it (in `experimental/future` header)

Comment: `A way I thought of to sort of achieve this is to have the futures call a handler upon completion`. How do you want to check their completion? You must periodically check their states or have another thread or task to wait on them.

Comment: @MRB The `wait_any` function will wait on a condition variable, which will be notified by the completion handler called by the first future that becomes ready.

Comment: OK but as I understand you want a non-blocking `wait_any` function. If you don't want to use a busy loop you need a separate task that it's work is just waiting on one of those futures and upon it's future returned, it call notify on condition variable.

Comment: @MRB Sorry but I don't seem to understand; I do want `wait_any` to be blocking. What I mean is to have each future try to call the completion handler upon completion, which in turn notify the condition variable, so that we don't have to busy-wait.

Comment: If you are not locked on std::future and want to wait until the Concurrency TS is fully implemented then `boost::future` is an alternative that implements the required functionality.

Comment: even the 2x proposal you mentioned in an anaemic shadow of what boost already provides. The lack of continuations in the c++ threading library should be a cause of great shame to the committee.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have boost available, its threading capabilities far exceed the standard library.

This will be the case after c++17, and by the looks of things, even after c++20.

```
#include <future>
#include <vector>

#define BOOST_THREAD_VERSION 4
#include <boost/thread.hpp>


void wait_for_any(std::vector<boost::future<void>> & v)
{
    boost::wait_for_any(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Alternative 1:

Right now, this ain't possible, though, you could work around it by writing your own find-logic.

```
template<typename Iterator>
Iterator find_first_ready_future(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    return std::find_if(begin, end, [](auto &future) { return future.wait_for(0s) == std::future_status::ready; }
}

template<typename T>
std::future<T> wait_until_an_element_is_ready(std::vector<std::future<T>> &vector)
{
    assert(!vector.empty());
    auto iterator = vector.end();
    do
    {
        // force switch of threads (if you don't want a busy loop, you might want to sleep this thread)
        // If reaction speed is very important, you might want to skip this first yield/sleep in the first iteration.
        std::this_thread::yield();

        iterator = find_first_ready_future(vector.begin(), vector.end());
    } while (iterator == vector.cend());
    auto result = std::move(*iterator);
    vector.erase(iterator); // Remove the ready future to prepare for the next call. (You ain't allowed to call .get() twice)
    return result;
}
```

Please note that all futures have to be created with the 'async' flag, because this will become an infinite loop if they are 'deferred'.

PS: If you don't want this to be blocking for your main thread, you might want to execute this in its own thread/future.

### Alternative 2:

Another alternative would be to wrap your futures to execute the task. This is a bit similar to the `future.then` proposal:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<std::future<void>> executeOnComplete(std::vector<std::future<T>> &&v)
{
    std::vector<std::future<void>> result;
    result.reserve(v.size());
    for (auto &f : v)
       result.emplace(std::async(std::launch::async,
                [f = std::move(f)] { process(f.get()); }));
    return result;
}
```

This alternative creates a new thread for each future and will block it until the original future is ready. It comes with the risk that you create too many threads.

PS: With some fancy `result_of` template logic, you can even create futures which return the result of `process

Comment: This is a busy wait though; using a condition variable would be better performance-wise.

Comment: This is indeed a busy wait, though, it favors executing in other threads and using condition variables results in having to adapt the code executed in the futures. (or wrapping them in other futures). If reaction speed ain't important, one could aways use sleep instead. (Let me clarify this in my answer)